# Selenium List <WebElement> always returns null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium `List<WebElement>` returns zero when `getoption` is used to retrieve values from a drop-down menu.

Code snippet:

```
public class FaceBookdropDownMenu {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.getProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//usr//local//bin//geckodriver 6");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

        WebElement month_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
        //return a list of month names
        System.out.println(month_dropdown.getText());
        List<WebElement> month_lists = driver.findElements(By.id("month"));   
        int total_month= month_lists.size();
        // returns 1 instead of 12 
        System.out.println("Total month count is"+ total_month);

        for(WebElement ele:month_lists) {
            String month_name = ele.getText();
            System.out.println("Months are:"+ month_name); 
        }
    }
}
```

======================================================================
I use the `getOptions()` but it does not  work either

```
WebElement month_dropdown =driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
System.out.println(month_dropdown.getText());
Select month_dd = new Select(month_dropdown);
List <WebElement> month_lists = month_dd.getOptions();       
int total_month= month_lists.size();
//Zero is returned instead of 12
System.out.println("Total month count is"+ total_month);

for(WebElement ele:month_lists) {
    String month_name = ele.getText();
    System.out.println("Months are:"+ month_name);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  I feel like you are not far off, but it's difficult to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to display the total number of months (12) and list the month names,  January to December

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML

Comment: What versions of `Selenium` and FireFox are you using? try using the second code snippets with older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class FacebookDateSelect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement month_dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("month")));
        Select month_dd = new Select(month_dropdown);
        List <WebElement> month_lists = month_dd.getOptions();       
        int total_month= month_lists.size();
        System.out.println("Total month count is"+ total_month);

        for(WebElement ele:month_lists) {
            String month_name = ele.getText();
            System.out.println("Months are:"+ month_name);
        }

        //updated code - to select random option using Random class
        month_dd.selectByIndex(new Random().nextInt(user_country.getOptions().size()));
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

In your code,

```
List<WebElement> month_lists = driver.findElements(By.id("month"));
```

always returns ONE element as there is only one element with id `month`. This does return the options inside of it (use getOptions method)

The other change I made is to use `WebDriverWait`, to have explicit wait condition (until month dropdown is displayed on the web page), check for the given duration (20 seconds). If the element found in first second itself, the element will be returned, it won't wait till 20 seconds. Similarly, if the element is not found after 20 seconds, `Timeout` exception will be thrown.

Output I got:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 6720
Only local connections are allowed.
Total month count is13
Months are:Month
Months are:Jan
Months are:Feb
Months are:Mar
Months are:Apr
Months are:May
Months are:Jun
Months are:Jul
Months are:Aug
Months are:Sept
Months are:Oct
Months are:Nov
Months are:Dec
```

Comment: The OP already tried using `Select` and it didn't work for him. And how does `getText()` from the dropdown solves the problem?

Comment: @Guy   the same code posted by OP worked for me when I ran without any modifications. Added the output for both `getText` and `getOptions` methods. So, I thought it is an issue related to page loading, so updated the code with `Explicit Wait`. OP, please update me whether the code worked,

Comment: The `// first option - using getText method` comment was added by you, it seems like you are suggesting it as a solution.

Comment: The explicit wait might have helped if the problem was locating the dropdown. The problem is `getOptions()` doesn't return the options under the dropdown.

Comment: @Guy, thanks for suggestion. Removed `getText` as it is not the preferred way of retrieving the OPTIONS. I think that the problem is due to slow loading the page, as the code is working fine for me. you can also try it out and see if the problem is reproduced at your end.

Comment: Expanding on the code, i want to randomly select a month. i try the following :Get all options
 java.util.List <WebElement> month_lists = month_dd.getOptions();
   Random r = new Random();
   WebElement random_month = month_lists.get(r.nextInt(month_lists.size()));
   System.out.println("The month select at random is:"+random_month);
   
output:

Comment: output: The month select at random is:[[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (c55ae7814dd28bfxxxxxxxx)] -> id: month]] -> tag name: option]
Month are :Month

Comment: java.util.List <WebElement> month_lists =driver.findElements(By.tagName("Month"));                                                       output:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive

Comment: updated the code with following line `month_dd.selectByIndex(new Random().nextInt(user_country.getOptions().size()));`. pls try.

Comment: user_country is not reference in the  code: month_dd.selectByIndex(new Random().nextInt(user_country.getOptions().size()));
  month_dd.selectByIndex(new Random().nextInt(month_dd.getOptions().size())); --- no avail either

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. Forgot to edit the code. What is the error when second one is used?? (using month_dd.getOptions().size());)

Comment: java.util.List <WebElement> month_lists = month_dd.getOptions(); Output:The month select at random is:[[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (7336fcdxxxxxxxxxx)] -> id: month]] -> tag name: option]

Comment: What you posted is not an error. What is the actual problem??